# Was the .question-hyperlink:visited colour unintentionally changed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

The colour for visited question links, `.question-hyperlink:visited`, was changed here on MSO to the same colour that is used on MSE. It looks a bit strange in the colour scheme used here on MSO.

Was the change unintentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure that was an accident; fallout from the introduction of unified theming. It'll be back to what it was before in the next build.

Comment: But now I'm used to muted, understated blue :visited links... Oh, well. I guess I'll adjust somehow when we go back to normal.

Comment: This bug has reappeared.

Comment: @Stijn Indeed. Looking.

Comment: @Stijn Fixed in the next build. Wrong variable name in the theme configuration that used to work (by accident) until a recent change. Thanks for the ping!