# Why is Meta Stack Overflow so...bright today?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This doesn't seem right - the links are normally a subdued gray, but today they're red.  What gives?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps [another unintentional change because of the unified theming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369424/was-the-question-hyperlinkvisited-colour-unintentionally-changed)

Comment: Blood moon, perhaps?

Comment: On my screen I still see a moody maroon colour.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  Wasn't that like, two weeks ago?

Comment: @Makoto http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @Servy:  That might be the case, but it looks just as bright in an incognito window.

Comment: @Makoto I was referring to why it took two weeks for the blood moon to affect you.  (Although I wouldn't be surprised if your issue is in fact related to portions of the old theme still being cached and others not, because my screen doesn't look like that.  Note that it's not just your browsers cache that is involved here.)

Comment: Ah, I see now @Servy.  Unfortunately since I don't get to see the moon as much as I'd like, that value never made its way into my cache.  I was only informed of the even through weak and phantom references to it.

Comment: I was looking for a duplicate to know if I should complain about this myself, and I'm glad to see you already had it covered.

Comment: @Makoto It's the new "Welcoming" theme. The old one was too dark for people

Comment: All the questions are red except this one on Meta

Comment: @awesomeguy It's the difference between visited and unvisited links.

Comment: must have not noticed the change

Comment: This is painful. I might just stop visiting Meta during the 6-8 weeks they'll take to change this.

Comment: This should have been fixed and will go out in the next build. Just shy of 8 weeks!

Comment: I was kinda hoping we could keep it, then I could stop crossing out links I've already clicked with lipstick. Oh well.

Comment: @AaronShekey Would you mind posting an answer so the community user doesn't bump this post every 30 days until someone does something about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should have been fixed and will go out in the next build ✌️